# What is causing visual studio errors looking for defaultbinder.cs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mscorlib

Just reinstalled visual studio 2019 as I was getting this error: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18814

I have never seen it before.  After reinstalling, I no longer see it but I get something else.  "Source not found" looking for defaultbinder.cs when running my WPF application from the debugger.  Running it outside of the debugger works fine.

I know I have seen this before but I couldn't find any info on the web.  -
[image]

> $exception    {"Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object."} System.NullReferenceException

> at System.DefaultBinder.BindToMethod(BindingFlags bindingAttr, MethodBase[] match, Object[]& args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String[] names, Object& state) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\defaultbinder.cs:line 66
> at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.DynamicMethodRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(Type type, Object[] args)
> at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)

[image]

Comment: Do you have any thirdparty or customized control in the project? Will you get this exception in a new project?

Comment: Confirm if Enable Just My Code checked in `Debug → Options → Debugging → General`.

Comment: I do not get this exception if I create a new project or with other projects.  I do have custom controls

Comment: Just my code got me again.  Thanks Kyle and shingo!

Answer (score 0):

As Kyle mentioned, just my code should be enabled.  This allowed me to start the application.  Hope this helps someone else or if no one else, me when I come looking for it a year from now.